# Array is undefined from Veux Store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, undefined

I am retrieving data from the Vuex Store. I first of all want to check of the array is present in the Vuex Store, after that I want to check if the noProducts object at index 0 is not present.

The reason for this is that tweakwiseSortedProducts is used for both products and a no Products boolean to react to in the front-end

```
tweakwiseHasProducts () {
  if (this.$store.state.tweakwise?.tweakwiseSortedProducts) {
    return (
      this.$store.state.tweakwise.tweakwiseSortedProducts[0].noProducts ===
      false
    );
  }
  return false;
},
```

My front-end currently, often, returns:

```
this.$store.state.tweakwise.tweakwiseSortedProducts[0] is undefined
```

In the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because tweakwiseSortedProducts is not undified but an empty list. You can try:

```
tweakwiseHasProducts () {
  if (this.$store.state.tweakwise?.tweakwiseSortedProducts?.length !== 0) {
    return (
      this.$store.state.tweakwise.tweakwiseSortedProducts[0].noProducts ===
      false
    );
  }
  return false;
},
```

or just:

```
tweakwiseHasProducts () {
  return this.$store.state.tweakwise?.tweakwiseSortedProducts[0]?.noProducts === false;
},
```

which will be false if any of this elements is undefined, or true if noProducts is really false

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use getter when calling a value in Vuex.
Please refer to the following.

```
  getters: {
    getTweakwiseSortedProducts: (state: any) => {
      return state.tweakwise?.tweakwiseSortedProducts || [];
    },
  },
```

---

```
tweakwiseHasProducts () {    
  this.$store.getters.getTweakwiseSortedProducts.length ? true : false;
}
```